# Draw and estimate the lenght of a line in a image using matlab

Tags: matlab, line, draw

I would like to draw a line between two edges on a grayscale image and estimate its length. Need to estimate the diameter of the femoral head. I have tried using houghlines and finally plot (see below) but can't get the code right. I am new to matlab which is probably why. Would be thankful for any hints!

```
for img = imread(sample);
figure,imshow(img)
hold on
p1 = [10,100];
p2 = [100,20];
plot([p1(2),p2(2)],[p1(1),p2(1)],'Color','r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;
pause;
end
```

Comment: Do you know how much actual distance one pixel represents?

Comment: And: can you post whatever you have now, no matter how bad you think it is? Gives us a better place to start off from...Just edit it below your question.

Comment: Also, an example picture that is representative of the general problem would help...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upload the image cause I am a new user..It's a cropped image from an hip xray, showing the hip ball and the head of the femor (tighbone). I don't know the actual distance but for now it will be enough knowing the distance in pixels.

Comment: Well I don't know the start and end points, I thought this was a general plot code that I could use. What I want to do is to draw a line between an unidentified point to another and then estimate the lenght of that line. So maybe plot is not the way, would you be familiar with a dragging/drawing function?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the start and end points of the line

```
p1 = [ 10 100];
p2 = [100  20];
```

then the distance in pixels would simply follow from the Pythagorean theorem:

```
dist = sqrt( (p2-p1) * (p2-p1).' );
```

Then multiply this by however many millimeters a pixel represents to get the actual distance.

If you don't know the points, but draw them manually (perhaps *aided* by computer vision, but never fully reliant on it :), see bdecaf's answer.

Comment: Well I don't, I thought this was a general plot code that I could use. What I want to do is to draw a line between an unidentified point to another. I also found this function here on the forum 'ButtonDownFcn',@startDragFcn

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how you obtain the points. Suppose it's not trivial.

For similar problems my users always want to be able to mark the points manually (they don't trust computer vision a bit). The code the looks like this:

```
pos = ginput(2);
l = line(pos(:,1),pos(:,2),'Color','r','Marker','o'); % just for visualization
distance = norm(pos(1,:)-pos(2,:));
```

Comment: thank you so much! It works, if l is the lenght of the line in pixels then the pos values must be the x,y coordinates for the start/end of line is that correct? Now I just need to find out how I can find out how many mm a pixel represents. I guess one way would be to take an xray with an object of a known lenght and then do the math from there.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Xrays - make sure if you need some perspective correction. Most simple would be to have an reference object in the picture, that way you will be save when the picture gets preprocessed. Personally I'd just use a coin - due to its circular shape even if it's not perfectly planar the longer side of the ellipse will still have the correct length. And it's quite easy to obtain ;)

Comment: Oh and to your question `l` is just the handle to line in the picture - for calculation it's not necessary - pos - contains all the coordinates - one column is `[x;y]`. It's useful - cause you can delete it with `delete(l)` - in case you want to correct yourself.